# license and protect php script

Tags: php, licensing, scripting

I am interested to use http://www.phplicengine.com to protect my php code and license my php script but have no clue how good it is. is here a PHPLicengine user who may help me please?

Comment: For best results, pretend you're on Jeopardy and phrase your post in the form of a question.  What kind of help are you looking for?

Comment: check out: http://www.ioncube.com they have a way to do it

Answer (score 12):

PHP code cannot be encrypted because at some point you have to eval() the string that will be producing the output.So there isn't a way to actually keep people from stealing your code if you let it get off your servers.

For the most part, trying to protect the code is useless. People make money off of code by either A) Working for someone, B) Providing updates/support to only valid paying customers, or C) Somehow make the data the software uses go through their own servers to get to the client.

Any other attempt to protect the code requires legal counsel and action.

Answer (score 7):

By itself, a system like PHPLicengine is useless. Your PHP script will still be a plain text PHP script, so someone can just strip the license code out (it'll take 1/10th as long as it took you to integrate), and do whatever they like with it.

PHP script encoders (like IonCube, Zend Encoder) have the ability to pre-compile PHP scripts into bytecode. They require the web server to have a PHP extension to decode and run the compiled scripts.

They basically do the same thing as obfuscators in Java / .NET - create an obfuscated binary version that still runs, but is more difficult to decompile or modify.

There are problems with this approach - not all web hosts have the appropriate PHP extension installed, and each script encoder needs it's own. Even those that do will typically have only one (IonCube and Zend are the most common). Typically, your customers won't be able to install the appropriate PHP extension, since they don't own or control their web server, so only having an obfuscated version available might prevent some customers from using (and therefore buying) your software.

Judging from the FAQs on the PHPLicengine website, the licensing portions of their license system are encoding using IonCube anyway, so that pretty much forces you into using IonCube.

Comment: Besides, at least a Zend Decoder exists and is working great :)

Answer (score 3):

You can compile php code. It is not a simple process though. Take a look at Bcompiler or byte compiler on the php.net site.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/intro.bcompiler.php

Answer (score 2):

i suggest You can use **cron** for check license every hour if system found fake licence key plugin for code destroyed.
but if you sale your plugin to 20000 user there are difficult to handle it...

Comment: Add `!` before the license checking line - i just broke your licensing system.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of PHPLicengine - for encryption/protection, I normally rely on either [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/) or [ionCube](http://www.ioncube.com/). I've also heard good things about [PHPAudit](http://solidphp.com/products/phpaudit/index.php).

However, whilst these (especially Zend) are all "big names" in the PHP script protection business, they cannot protect your script against really serious crackers (I know both Zend and IonCube have been broken before: however, this was several versions ago and the resulting output was obfuscated anyway as both systems, for speed, reduced variables/function names to minimal length and removed comments).

Answer (score 0):

You can protect your code with [ioncube](http://www.ioncube.com/)
I haven't used it, but I know one host that supports it: [mittwald](http://www.mittwald.de/)

Answer (score -1):

Hi all you can try with them to encrypt with license key your php code/source/script

I have found on internet this service you can try it is cheap

https://www.facebook.com/pages/Encrypt-with-License-Key-any-PHP-Code/1408496709369712

Comment: Have you tried it out..?