# License key for magento extension

Tags: php, magento, license-key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [license and protect php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157425/license-and-protect-php-script)

I have a custom Magento extension, and I want to create a license key for it (like windows key).

I will use `include` method from remote server to check the license key (I am not sure that this is the best choice).

When I have to use include method to check the license key, I think if I do this every time when I use the extension, the site will load slowly.

Can you give me some idea how can I do that or may be give me advice for another decision?

Comment: Any method you use to validate the key would probably be easily bypassed by just editing the source (php isn't encrypted/obfuscated) and having your validation function return `true` (or whatever the expected return value).

Comment: Also, any obfuscation is easily bypassed by just renaming variables. Any home brew encryption then eval scheme is easily bypassed because you have to have some code unencrypted to decrypt/eval and you can just echo out the source before eval (not to mention eval==evil and eval is disabled on several hosts for safety). There are some php source encryption shemes, but they all require some sort of php extension and the server would have to have this installed to work. The most common is zend guard which will have the most availability on servers, but no where near 100% and not 100% foolproof.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157425/license-and-protect-php-script

Comment: What if your remove server goes down, is inaccessible or slow? Can you guarantee an SLA for your customers? This is one of many reasons why this is pretty bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

There's no great solution for this.  Windows license keys work because windows is a binary executable.  It's non trivial to look at a the Window's machine code and extract the rules for license keys.

A phone home solution, as you mentioned, won't work due to network latency issues. Beyond that, it would be trivially easy to strip the phone home check from the extension.

You can look into applications like Ion Cube or Zend Guard Loader, which allow you to protect certain PHP files with binary-like machine code.  The problem with these approaches is you're requiring your customer to install an extra PHP extension to use your code. Beyond the hassle of helping customers get these installed, these extensions also come with a performance overhead.

Your best approach?  If you're selling the extension, set a fair-but-high price. Trust your customers, maybe add a trivial license key to some installer routine, and tie ongoing extension upgrades to a license registration. Also, if it's relevant to the problem you're solving, giving away the extension adding a cloud component people need to pay for is another option.

If you really want to sell software that's tightly tied to a license key ala-windows, Indie Mac development, etc., then PHP isn't the right platform to target.

Comment: Using ionCube or Zend Guard is the most common approach I have encountered with licensed magento module. Since the code is pre-compiled there is no way to see if it cashes any results or make a request every time.